# config yml for mybatis different level

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, mybatis

```
logging:
  level:
    root: info
    com:
      demo:
        mapper: debug
            insertBigData: info
```

I want to see my mybatis sql in debug model, but there a function which inser a huge value, and I want to ignore this special function, but yml seem don't support config this style
I know move the function to another mapper is a way. what else can I do to ignore log of function insertBigData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be ideal, but specifying partially-qualified key seems to be working.

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    root: info
    com:
      demo:
        mapper: debug
        mapper.insertBigData: info
```

Comment: Here is a portable [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-64966169). You should be able to see that different log level is applied to the statements.